# RxJava: How to update value of List in onErrorResumeNext

Tags: android, rx-java

I'm trying to update the validate the list and update the value accordingly but when I'm getting an error, the process gets stopped. I'm calling it in ViewModel class as:

```
fun validateList(list: List<Model>): Single<List< Model >> {
    return Observable.fromIterable(list)
        .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
        .flatMapSingle { validate() }
        .toList()
        .map { list.mapIndexed { index, testModel ->  
               (if (it[index] != null) {
                testModel.isVerified = it[index].toString()
                 } else throw Exception("ERROR")); testModel }
       }
        .onErrorResumeNext { error -> }
```

And I'm calling it from fragment as:

```
private fun verify() {
    showLoading(true)
    testViewModel.validateList(arrayList)
        .doFinally {
            showLoading(false)
        }
        .asyncToUiSingle()
        .subscribe({
            adjustCard(it)
        }, {
            it.printStackTrace()
        })
        .addTo(disposables)
}
```

**TestModel**:

```
 data class TestModel(
    val title: String,
    var isVerified: String? = null,
    var reason: String? = null )
```

Please help me to understand how I can update value of reason field in list if one element gets failed status and continue the validations for other elements.

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: Sorry I'm new for Rx so I want too handle case of exception when it[index] will not get any Boolean value.

Comment: you say the 'process  gets  stopped'. Does it mean that your app is crashing ?

Comment: onErrorResumeNext gets called if any exception is thrown in the chain execution. I do not see how that may happen in your case

Comment: Ok. Got and updated snippet also. Where will I have to handle exception then?

Comment: Why are your throwing the exception instead of updating the TestModel directly?

Comment: I'm new into RxJava so not aware of everything.

Answer (score 0):

`onErrorResumeNext` require return an ObservableSource and it will be invoke directly after error happened:

```kotlin
. onErrorResumeNext { error -> 
    val newList = // Code for new list with updated data
    Observable.just(newList) // The new list will be emit to subscriber
}
```

In your case, I think you can use `retry`, it will be continue the chain after error happened with given condition, let try:

```kotlin
var index = 0
val validatedList = mutableListOf<Model>()
return Observable.fromIterable(list)
//...
.map {
  for (i in index until list.size) {
    val testModel = list[i];
    if (testModel != null) {
       testModel. isVerified = testModel.toString()
       validatedList.add(testModel);
    } else {
       throw Exception("ERROR");
    }
  }
  validatedList
}
.retry { error ->
  error.printStackTrace()
  index++
  index < list.size
}
```

That's mean when error happened, the `retry` will trigger and continue the chain if u didn't in the end of list. But, I don't think that's best practice, you maybe try another way. Hope can help you.

Comment: Could you please tell me how I'll update value here at particular index for reason variable in existing list?

Comment: You can create custom exception class, like: `class ReasonInvalid(val index: Int, val msg: String) : Exception(msg)`, and then `throw ReasonInvalid(<index>, "ERROR")` in `map`

Comment: But it'll be static error message. I want to update dynamic `Throwable.printStackTrace()` as a reason.

Comment: can you please help?

Comment: If u throw a exception, the chain will be end and error handler will invoke. I suggestion you instead of `throw Exception` in `map`, you can update reason, like: `if (it[index] != null) {..// code } else { // update reason error here}`.

Comment: But error will be static in this case. I want error through Throwable. Right now I get exception in subscriber if any list item gets an exception.

Comment: @AnshulTyagi I got u, please check my edited answer.